# Why am I getting a JSON deserializing error with a REST API?

Tags: json, api, deserialization, restsharp

I am trying to access  COVID19 JSON formatted data through an API using REST Sharp but get an error when I try to deserialize per below. I am new to Rest Sharp. Not sure what I am missing.

C# code
        public void getCOVIDData() {

```
        var client = new RestClient("https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/country?format=json&name=France");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com");
        request.AddHeader("x-rapidapi-key", constants.apiKey);

        IRestResponse<COVID_Data.RootObject> response = client.Execute<COVID_Data.RootObject>(request);

        //the below line returns a JSON object without a problem
        string covidData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response.Content).ToString();

        //this line returns NewtonSoft.JSON.JSON.SerializationException error (see screen shot)
        COVID_Data.RootObject data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<COVID_Data.RootObject>(response.Content);
    }
```

The object returned is

[
  {
    "country": "France",
    "code": "FR",
    "confirmed": 181575,
    "recovered": 63354,
    "critical": 1794,
    "deaths": 28239,
    "latitude": 46.227638,
    "longitude": 2.213749,
    "lastChange": "2020-05-20T14:53:01-04:00",
    "lastUpdate": "2020-05-21T10:15:02-04:00"
  }
]

When I try to create a COVID_Data class and deserialize to a RootObject I get the below exception error.

￼[JSON](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dAX0.png)

The COVID_Class is set up per below.

public class COVID_Data
    {

```
    public class  RootObject
    {
        [JsonProperty("country")]
        public  string country { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("code")]
        public string code { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("confirmed")]
        public int confirmed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("recovered")]
        public int recovered { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("critical")]
        public int critical { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("deaths")]
        public int deaths { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("latitude")]
        public double latitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("longitude")]
        public double longitude { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastChange")]
        public string lastChange { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("lastUpdate")]
        public string lastUpdate { get; set; }
    }


}
```

Comment: The root of that JSON is an *array*, not that object.

Comment: Thanks. Still a little fuzzy how to address in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work using a JArray and then iterating JTokens.

JArray array = JArray.Parse(response.Content);

string outputText = "";

string twoNewLines = Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;

```
        foreach (JToken pair in array)  

          outputText = "Country: " + array[0]["country"] + twoNewLines +
                "Confirmed: " + array[0]["confirmed"] + twoNewLines +
                "Recovered: " + array[0]["recovered"] + twoNewLines +
                "Critical: " + array[0]["critical"] + twoNewLines +
                "Deaths: " + array[0]["deaths"] + twoNewLines +
                "Last Update: " + array[0]["lastUpdate"];
```

outputText in [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqnZy.png)